# Aggregating table values by dates in table [SQL]

Tags: sql

I have a table with cust_id, sku, date, order_number (if it's that customer's 1st, 2nd...) and amount.  My end goal is to find the total spent by each customer during their first year (exact dates will be relative to each customer).

The sales data table is rld_sales with the following columns:

- cust_id
- sku,
- date of purchase,
- order number (if it's that customer's 1st or 2nd...)

```
-- CREATES TABLE OF CUSTOMER_ID AND Y1, Y2 [END DATES]
CREATE TABLE customer_timetable AS (SELECT
    rld_sales. "customer_id" AS cust_id,
    CAST(date(rld_sales."date") + INTERVAL '1 year' AS DATE) as y1,
    CAST(date(rld_sales."date") + INTERVAL '2 year' AS DATE) as y2
FROM
    rld_sales
WHERE
    transaction_order = 1
GROUP BY
    rld_sales. "customer_id",
    date
);

-- JOINS CUSTOMER_TIMETABLE WITH RLD_SALES
CREATE TABLE t1 AS (
    SELECT
        customer_timetable.cust_id,
        customer_timetable.y1,
        customer_timetable.y2,
        rld_sales.*
    FROM
        customer_timetable
        JOIN rld_sales ON (customer_timetable.cust_id = rld_sales.customer_id)
);


SELECT
    t1. "cust_id",
    SUM(t1. "amount"),
    SUM(t2. "amount")
FROM
    t1
WHERE
    CAST(date AS DATE) BETWEEN y1
    AND y2
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            t1. "amount"
        FROM
            t1
        WHERE
            CAST(date AS DATE) > t1. "y2") t2 ON t1. "cust_id" = t2. "cust_id"
    GROUP BY
        t1. "cust_id"
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            customer_timetable;
```

So far I've had minimal success creating intermediate tables and joining one at a time, but I feel like there has to be a much more elegant way to make it all happen in a single query.

Comment: But whats the question you like to ask here?

Comment: Please tag appropriate database name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guess you are using MySQL database, This following query will give you some guideline of writing standard SQL to achieve your requirement-

```
SELECT 
A.customer_id,
CASE 
    WHEN A."date" >= DATE_ADD(CAST(NOW() AS DATE), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) THEN 'Last_Year'
    WHEN A."date" >= DATE_ADD(CAST(NOW() AS DATE), INTERVAL -2 YEAR) THEN 'Last_Previous_Year'
    ELSE 'Before_That'
END 'Year',
SUM(amount) -- Not sure your amount in which table. Add Table Alias before the coulmn name if required
FROM rld_sales A
INNER JOIN customer_timetable B ON A.customer_id = B.cust_id 
GROUP BY 
A.customer_id,
CASE 
    WHEN A."date" >= DATE_ADD(CAST(NOW() AS DATE), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) THEN 'Last_Year'
    WHEN A."date" >= DATE_ADD(CAST(NOW() AS DATE), INTERVAL -2 YEAR) THEN 'Last_Previous_Year'
    ELSE 'Before_That'
END
```

To get yearly values per column ID wise, use this following query-

```
SELECT  A.customer_id,
SUM(CASE WHEN A."Year" = 'Last_Year'  THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) 'Last_Year',
SUM(CASE WHEN A."Year" = 'Last_Previous_Year'  THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) 'Last_Previous_Year',
SUM(CASE WHEN A."Year" = 'Before_That'  THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) 'Before_That'
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    A.customer_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN A."date" >= DATE_ADD(CAST(NOW() AS DATE), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) THEN 'Last_Year'
        WHEN A."date" >= DATE_ADD(CAST(NOW() AS DATE), INTERVAL -2 YEAR) THEN 'Last_Previous_Year'
        ELSE 'Before_That'
    END 'Year',
    SUM(amount) Amount -- Not sure your amount in which table. Add Table Alias before the coulmn name if required
    FROM rld_sales A
    INNER JOIN customer_timetable B ON A.customer_id = B.cust_id 
    GROUP BY 
    A.customer_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN A."date" >= DATE_ADD(CAST(NOW() AS DATE), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) THEN 'Last_Year'
        WHEN A."date" >= DATE_ADD(CAST(NOW() AS DATE), INTERVAL -2 YEAR) THEN 'Last_Previous_Year'
        ELSE 'Before_That'
    END
)A
GROUP BY A.customer_id
```

Comment: You are most welcome. Its a nice feeling when something really help other :)

Comment: You are most welcome. Its a nice feeling when something really help other :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  Is there a way that I can make the time query into a column instead of a row?  Ideally I would end up with the following table structure:`

customer_id | Last_Year | Last_Previous_Year | Before_That
cust_1          |       50       |            25                  |        40`

I had to delete my original thank you as I couldn't edit it.  Sorry.  I really do appreciate it and will pay if forward.

Comment: @NatAnderson please check the new query added.

Comment: @mrRabbani Last follow-up.  There is also a column 'Category1' on each row of the rld_sales table.  I thought that I would be able to extrapolate your answer to not only create a column for a date, but I would also like to have a column for each category (i.e. last_year_category1, last_year_category2, last_previous_year_category1, last_year_category2...).  I tried inserting this logic into the where statement and am getting an aggregation error.  Thoughts?  Thanks again!

Comment: Try with adding the new column in both select and group by part like  - A.customer_id,Category1,

Comment: Thanks again!  I'm all set now.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select s.customer_id, sum(s.amount)
from rld_sales s
where s.date < (select min(s2.date) + interval 1 year
                from rld_sales s2
                where s2.customer_id = s.customer_id
               )
group by s.customer_id;
```

Temporary tables would only seem to make this query more complicated.